# Is there an easier way to remove single vertices in mesh than delete and reconnect?

Tags: modeling, mesh

When stiching two meshes together sometimes the number of vertices don't match.

I could delete the red vertices and reconnect the remaining with *Make Edge* <kbd>F</kbd>.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, like adding a vertex using Subdivide <kbd>W</kbd>?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean is there a way to remove vertices without deleting the edge they're part of? X> Dissolve Vertices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dissolve a vertex with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Vertices* or you could also get rid of it by merging it to the next closest one by selecting it, selecting the other choosing a merge option (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>).